Two cards are drawn from an ordinary poker deck of 52 playing cards one by one with replacement. find Probability of getting the same number or letter
Suppose 2 cards are drawn from an ordinary poker deck of 52 playing cards one by one with replacement. Find the probability of getting the same number or letter.
attempt:
There are $4$ type of cards. We choose $2$ out of them, so there are $C(4,2)=6$ ways.
For those cards with the same number, since there are $9$ numbers (from $2$ till $10$), there are $6 \times 9 = 54$ ways to do this. For those cards with the same lettter, since there are $4$ letters (A, J, Q, K), then there are $6 \times 4 = 24$ ways.
In total, there are $54+24=78$ ways to do this. The sample space is given by $C(52,2)=1326$.
Hence, the probability is
$$\frac{78}{1326} = \frac{1}{17}.$$
I'm in doubt whether it is correct. Any helps? Many thanks in advanced.

"same number or letter" would be better stated as "same rank" because we usually do not refer to face cards and aces as letters so it looks like a typo for "same number or better".  This also makes it clear that you should only consider the $13$ different ranks instead of separating the numbers and letters.  Presumably the types of cards you talk about are the suits, but suits do not matter at all for this.

Without loss of generality, the first card drawn is the Ace of Spades.  That is, the probability of the 2nd card's rank matching the first card's rank is unaffected by which card was drawn first.

If you draw with replacement you can get the same card twice.  Your use of $C(4,2)$ and $C(9,2)$ insists that the cards have different suits.  That is equivalent to drawing without replacement and leads to your error.
The first card has a certain rank.  You are asking the probability that the second card has the same rank.  As you are drawing with replacement, there are $4$ cards of $52$ that will be a success, so the probability is $\frac 4{52}=\frac 1{13}$

Thanks for the explanation. It was very clear.
